# Is there a way to poll several futures simultaniously in rust async

Tags: asynchronous, rust, parallel-processing

I'm trying to execute several sqlx queries in parallel given by a iterator.
This is probably the closest I've got so far.

```rust
let mut futures = HahshMap::new() // placeholder, filled HashMap in reality
    .iter()
    .map(async move |(_, item)| -> Result<(), sqlx::Error> {
        let result = sqlx::query_file_as!(
            // omitted
        )
            .fetch_one(&pool)
            .await?;
        channel.send(Enum::Event(result)).ignore();
        Ok(())
    })
    .clollect();
futures::future::join_all(futures);
```

All queries and sends are independent from each other, so if one of them fails, the others should still get processed.
Futthermore the current async closure is not possible like this.

Comment: What is wrong with `join_all()` If you want to do something once any of the completes use [`select_all()`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/future/fn.select_all.html).

Comment: @HHK That the map doesn't work like this. Furthermore I want all futures to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust doesn't yet have `async` closures. You instead need to have the closure *return* an async block:

```rust
move |(_, item)| async move { ... }
```

Additionally, make sure you `.await` the future returned by `join_all` in order to ensure the individual tasks are actually polled.

Comment: Just some slight changes: Collect isn't working nor necessary. Stuff like the pool or channel need to be cloned outside of the async block since it would otherwise complain about `cannot move out of 'channel', a captured variable in an 'FnMut' closure`.